# iterate 5 times each characters in the alphabet

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

```
letters = list(string.ascii_letters)

for i in letters:    
    print(i*5)
```

my output:

```
aaaaa

bbbbb

ccccc

ddddd

eeeee

fffff

ggggg

hhhhh

......
```

The correct output:

```
['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc', 'ddddd', 'eeeee', 'fffff', 'ggggg', 'hhhhh', 'iiiii', 'jjjjj', 'kkkkk', 'lllll', 'mmmmm', 'nnnnn', 'ooooo', 'ppppp', 'qqqqq', 'rrrrr', 'sssss', 'ttttt', 'uuuuu', 'vvvvv', 'wwwww', 'xxxxx', 'yyyyy', 'zzzzz', 'AAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCC', 'DDDDD', 'EEEEE', 'FFFFF', 'GGGGG', 'HHHHH', 'IIIII', 'JJJJJ', 'KKKKK', 'LLLLL', 'MMMMM', 'NNNNN', 'OOOOO', 'PPPPP', 'QQQQQ', 'RRRRR', 'SSSSS', 'TTTTT', 'UUUUU', 'VVVVV', 'WWWWW', 'XXXXX', 'YYYYY', 'ZZZZZ']
```

Comment: `l = [i*5 for i in string.ascii_letters]`.

Answer (score 0):

The output you want is a list but what you are printing is individual element while generating them. First generate the list and then print it.
Here is the code snippet you can follow.

```
letters = list(string.ascii_letters)
l = [i*5 for i in letters]
print l
```

You can also merge first two lines

```
l = [i*5 for i in string.ascii_letters]
```